# How can I link a spinner to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

The code runs but is not linking the spinner to a cell.

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Criteria As Integer

    Criteria = InputBox("How many Criteria would you like to use")
    For i = 1 To Criteria
        wsTable.Spinners.Add(Cells(1, i).Left, Cells(1, i).Top, 69.5, 20).Select
        With Selection
            .LinkedCell = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(1, i))
        End With
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim Criteria As Integer

Criteria = InputBox("How many Criteria would you like to use")
For i = 1 To Criteria
    wsTable.Spinners.Add(Cells(1, i).Left, Cells(1, i).Top, 69.5, 20).Select
    With Selection
        .LinkedCell = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(1, i)).Address
    End With
Next
```